# Return typed value from enum associated value

Tags: swift

I have a enum like so:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case a(Int)
    case b(String)
    case c(Int)
}

let arrayOfMyEnums: [MyEnum] = [ .a(4), .b("hello"), .c(42) ]
```

Now I'd like to write an extension that returns the type of the associated value.

```
private extension MyEnum {
    // this does pseudo code
    func value() -> ...   // Should return typed associated value, so either Int or String
   { 

   }
}
```

Wonder whether this can be expressed somehow with generics so I can call `arrayOfMyEnums[0].value()` and would get an Int, whereas `arrayOfMyEnums[1].value()` would return a string?

Comment: It's impossible to express in `Swift` type system. Best you can do is to use `Any`, but that  won't be typed.

Comment: You are always going to need to use a `switch` here, one way or another

Comment: Sadly you cannot really use generics for this particular problem, since you essentially to be able to return a different type for each `enum` case. However, that is not possibly with the current type system of Swift.

Comment: The best you can do is to create two properties. One to return the integer value and the other to return the string value.